# Docker php_network_getaddresses error

Tags: php, mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have following Docker containers running that were generated by [PHPDocker](https://phpdocker.io/generator):

```
learn-php-mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: learn-php-mysql
  volumes:
    - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: learning
    MYSQL_DATABASE: learning
    MYSQL_USER: learning
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: learning

learn-php-webserver:
  image: phpdockerio/nginx:latest
  container_name: learn-php-webserver
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  links:
   - learn-php-php-fpm

learn-php-php-fpm:
  build: .
  dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
  container_name: learn-php-php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
  links:
    - learn-php-mysql:mysql
```

Everything works fine, except for when trying to connect to MySQL server via PHP code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("db", "learning", "learning", "learning");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

It will throw following error:

> Connect failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or
>   service not known

### Why does this happen?

.

.

You can find repository for this [here](https://github.com/genert/learn-php). And when running `docker-compose up` go to *http://localhost:8080/classes/serialize.php* to produce same error.

Comment: Why is `db` the hostname that you are using for the MySQL server? Shouldn't it be `localhost` or something?

Comment: @GrishaLevit It should be actually container's name. It works now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When making connection via PHP (or any other), use the container's name as host, which in case is **learn-php-mysql**.

Thus

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("learn-php-mysql", "learning", "learning", "learning");
```

Will work.