# Laravel Cron php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-5, cron

**Hello!**

So I have this annoying problem with setting up a cron job for Laravel scheduling.
To understand the problem, Here is the project architecture:

- The project is set up using docker (we have a container for php,and
  mysql and for nginx)
- The web application is built on Laravel 5.3

We want to automatize some tasks, so we created 3 commands and we gathered them inside the schedule to run them every day, here is how the `kernel.php` looks like:

```
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\IncompleteAccount',
        'App\Console\Commands\TirageSoon',
        'App\Console\Commands\WinzExpiration',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('incompleteaccount:run')->everyFiveMinutes()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron.log'));

        $schedule->command('tiragesoon:run')->everyFiveMinutes()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron.log'));

        $schedule->command('winzExpire:run')->everyFiveMinutes()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron.log'));
    }
```

And our crontab looks like:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

In the logs file we get this:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `booking` where `created_at` > 2017-08-27 16:08:50)  



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  



  [PDOException]                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  



  [PDOException]                                                                               
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  


No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

and finally the .env file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64:gPDQqknmG9YSOMueb/Ii0xXWQvrzOPsVFVRHVIzXXD0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://www.ourSite.com
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ourDB
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Also, I can ping to mysql from inside my container, and here is the docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

    volumes_source:
      image: tianon/true
      volumes:
          - ${SRCDIR}:/var/www
          - ${DATADIR}/data/uploads:/var/www/public/img/uploads




    nginx:
        image: nginx
        volumes_from:
          - volumes_source
        volumes:
            - ${SRCDIR}/dockers/etc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
            - ${SRCDIR}/dockers/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        ports:
           - "${HTTP_PORT}:80"
        links:
           - php:phpfpm

    wait:
        image: aanand/wait
        links:
           - mysql:mysql
### Workspace Utilities Container ###########################

    php:
        build: dockers/winsu
        volumes_from:
          - volumes_source
        command: php-fpm7 -F
        working_dir: /var/www
        environment:
            CONFIG_ENV: ${CONFIG_ENV}
        entrypoint: /var/www/dockers/winsu/run.sh
        volumes:
           - ${SRCDIR}/dockers/winsu/crontab:/crontab.file
        links:
           - mysql:mysql
           - wait:wait

### MySQL Container #########################################
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        volumes_from:
            - volumes_data
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: winsu
            MYSQL_USER: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

### Databases Data Container ################################

    volumes_data:
        image: tianon/true
        volumes:
            - ${DATADIR}/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - ${DATADIR}/data/storage:/var/www/storage
```

Been facing this problem for 3 days so far! would really appreciate it if you can help! **I already saw the similar questions, but nothing worked!** Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where and how is `mysql` defined in your dns?

Comment: I can ping to `mysql` normally, since its a container in the same server, check the screenshot above

Comment: how did you define `mysql`?

Comment: Defined it in my docker-compose file: `    mysql:
        image: mysql
        volumes_from:
            - volumes_data
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: winzup
            MYSQL_USER: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
`

Comment: hmm, you mentioned having seen multiple questions on here, but did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913471/docker-php-network-getaddresses-error ?

Comment: You are running crontab inside the php container?

Comment: @Quezler that's what I'm doing, if you see the .env file you'll find "mysql" in the db host

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes I'm running inside the php container

Comment: Can you try changing your cron command to this and see if helps `/bin/bash -lc "php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1"` and if that doesn't work then post your docker-compose file also to the question

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried using your command, but same output, Imma post the docker-compose file above

Comment: I believe i see the issue can you change your run statement to `CONFIG_ENV=<actualvalue> php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1`. Cron doesn't use the same environment variables that your bash would be having

Comment: the actualvalue stands for the `.env` file in the root of the laravel project right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153887/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-sletheren).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to environment variables not being picked up. When you run a command in cron two things are different

- current working directory
- environment variables

So change your command to

```
* * * * * cd /var/www && /var/www/artisan schedule:run ...
```

and define any additional needed variables using X=Y format prefixed before the command

```
* * * * * cd /var/www && X=Y Z=A /var/www/artisan schedule:run ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use artisan to prove your code.

In the php artisan commant you can put a -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

For example you can do:

```
php artisan incompleteaccount:run -v
```

And with this code if the code have error, the command returns you the information of the error with the line and all information about it.

Comment: how to add options inside the scheduler?

Comment: I think that your error are in the commands code. So I suggest you run first your task in the console: php artisan incompleteaccount:run -v (the -v provide you return all error traking of your code). With this you know if your code are ok or if have an error.

Comment: hello man, I tried running the command with the -v flag, it shows that it ran correctly `Executed Tirage soon command`